# iPhone CorePlot: Candle Stick , how to set more distance between every stick when zoom in and zoom out?

Tags: iphone, charts, core-plot

CorePlot: Candle Stick ,

how to set more distance between every stick when zoom in and zoom out?

When i try to zoom out, it looks really terrible.

How can i fix it?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You have several options:

1. Make the bars narrower using the `barWidth` property.
2. Filter your data to show fewer bars. Call `-reloadData` on the plot to load the filtered data.
3. Make the whole graph wider (probably not an option on iPhone, but may be practical in an iPad or Mac app).

Comment: how to Make the bars narrower?

Comment: @EricSkroch:  when is the best time to filter the data set? Should I begin filtering in the CPTPlotSpace Delegate willChangePlotRangeTo: method?  Or once didChangePlotRangeForCoordinate is called?

Comment: @timthetoolman It doesn't matter when you filter the data as long as the datasource returns the correct (filtered) data. The best approach probably depends on how you're acquiring the data and how often you're going to update the plot.

Comment: @EricSkroch:  let's consider the case where I have a large set of data  that has already been filtered to half the number of points and is zoomed out completely to the Global Range.  Now when the user begins to zoom in, I want to refilter the original data so that more detail is shown.  So when is the best time to trigger the filter and reload of data?  obviously I would probably want to utilize an NSTimer to coalace potential willChange and didChange method calls.

Comment: @timthetoolman In that case, I would wait until you know what the final zoom will be. You could do it when the timer finishes and right before you call `-reloadData`, or you could simply have the datasource do the filtering on the fly every time the plot loads its data as long as the filtering operation is fast.